# Does an evaporating black hole violate conservation of angular momentum?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, hawking-radiation

Angular momentum is supposed to be conserved, but when a rotating black hole evaporates the Hawking radiation comes out in straight lines. Doesn't this violate conservation of angular momentum?

Does a rotating black hole emit **more** Hawking radiation than a non-rotating one to avoid a violation of conservation of energy?

Comment: Electromagnetic radiation can carry angular momentum, even though it "comes out in straight lines". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_of_light

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'comes out in straight lines' (after all, the surrounding spacetime does not have spherical symmetry). I don't know but would guess that the angular momentum does emerge in the radiation.

Comment: ["Rotating black hole loses angular momentum due to Hawking radiation several times faster than it loses mass, so that it would spin down almost completely before it loses most of its mass."](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425511/85443)

Comment: @KeithMcClary What if we are talking about a micro black hole formed by an energetic cosmic ray collision? It wouldn't have enough time to lose its angular momentum.

Comment: @SurpriseDog The [abstract](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.14.3260) doesn't  say it is different for small BH.