# What portion of the total power emitted by the Sun comes from photons?

Tags: astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun, stellar-physics, solar-wind

We usually talk about luminosity, which is the total power from emitted photons. The other sources are neutrinos and the solar wind (which includes protons and other particles).

I assume that most of the emitted energy comes from photons. What portion comes from the other stuff?

Comment: Did you try the inter web? wiki-P says in the 1st paragraph that the neutrino luminosity is 0.023 L_sun. Likewise with the solar wind: $1.3 \times 10^{36} $particles (protons) per second. Assume 145 km per second and work it out. Gravitation waves? Search for $J_2$ for the sun and use this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33132/ . Please report back what you get.

Comment: I concur with what @JEB said, but the typical (asymptotic) solar wind speed is more like ~300-400 km/s.  The speed closer to the sun is, indeed, lower and it accelerates as it passes through the Alfven point (well, this is the current theory which will hopefully be tested by Parker Solar Probe).

Answer (score 1):

The solar electromagnetic luminosity is $3.83\times 10^{26}$ W and the neutrino luminosity is about [2.3% of this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_luminosity).

The solar luminosity referred to above does not include losses due to the solar wind, which are tiny and well inside the noise and variability (the solar luminosity varies at the 0.1% level during its magnetic activity cycle). Assuming a mass loss rate of $\sim 2\times 10^{-14} M_\odot$ per year moving with an average speed of $\sim 400$ km/s (typical values, which might vary by a factor of 2 and with solar latitude and cycle) implies a power output of just $\sim 10^{20}$ W.